# RetrieveAPIView must be called with a URL keyword argument

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

So I am trying to specify a lookup and I am getting the error

> Expected view GetEmployersEmailUnique_RetrieveAPIView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "user__email". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

This is what my url looks like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employer/email_available/?user__email=someEmaol@gmail.com
```

and this is what my url path looks like

```
url(r"^email_available/",GetEmployersEmailUnique_RetrieveAPIView.as_view()),
```

and this is what my view looks like

```
class GetEmployersEmailUnique_RetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = modelEmployer.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'user__email'
    serializer_class = Serializer_ListEmployer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
```

The `modelEmployer` has a one to one relation with the user model

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add a variable to your url. You need to do this when You use RetrieveAPIView. Your url should look like this:

```
url(
    r"^email_available/(?P<user__email>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$",
    GetEmployersEmailUnique_RetrieveAPIView.as_view()
),
```

Comment: my url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employer/email_available/someEmaol@gmail.com/`

Comment: my url.py is `url(r"^email_available/(?P<user__email>[\w+])/$",GetEmployersEmailUnique_RetrieveAPIView.as_view()),`

Comment: Try this one: `url(r"^email_available/(?P<user__email>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$",GetEmployersEmailUnique_RetrieveAPIView.as_view()),`